# SKEmitterNode doesn't work when used as a reference node within another reference node

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm having an issue with using a particle emitter with reference nodes.

It works when it's referenced directly in the scene (for example, inside the GameScene.sks file), but it doesn't work when it's referenced within another .sks file, and that file/node is then referenced in GameScene.sks, although other referenced nodes appear correctly.

Here's the hierarchy:

```
GameScene.sks
 - Reference Node to RocketFire.sks (emitter)  <-- works
 - Reference Node to Rocket.sks

Rocket.sks
 - Reference Node to RocketFire.sks (emitter)  <-- doesn't work in GameScene
 - Reference Node to Engine.sks (non-emitter nodes)  <-- works in GameScene

RocketFire.sks (SpriteKit particle file)

Engine.sks (SpriteKit scene file with non-emitter nodes)
```

Is there the wrong way to use Reference Nodes or particle emitters?

(Let me know if more info is needed)

**EDIT:**

I actually made it work *some of the time*. Sometimes it would suddenly start working when I remove and re-add the referenced nodes in all the files, or if I change the node hierarchy. But still, I can't identify a consistent reason for when it works and when it doesn't, because since changing it and putting it back to when it worked, doesn't fix it. (Feels like a bug, honestly)

Comment: It's not clear what behavior works and doesn't work are referring to, but maybe there's an issue with the emitter's simulation time.  E.g., the emitter has a certain duration, but it's getting created but not used/shown until later after the duration is over.  In which case, using the emitter's `isPaused` to keep it from running when it shouldn't be active and/or calling `resetSimulation()` to rewind it just before showing it might fix your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work = no particles are emitted (i.e. nothing is visible). I reproduced it with a new project and using only the Sprite scene editor - no other logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since iOS 10 all sprite nodes are by default paused. This includes your scene. It is not enough to just make your scene not paused (isPaused = false) you have to make the children not paused as well.

for your example I added to smoke emitters to my plane.sks file which is dragged onto my GameScene.sks file as an SKReferenceNode

and in my Plane.swift file, note I've put isPaused = false on one of the emitters and it still doesn't work

```
var leftSmoke: SKEmitterNode!
var rightSmoke: SKEmitterNode!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {

    if let leftSmoke = self.childNode(withName: "//leftSmoke") as? SKEmitterNode {
        self.leftSmoke = leftSmoke
        leftSmoke.isPaused = false
    }

    if let rightSmoke = self.childNode(withName: "//rightSmoke") as? SKEmitterNode {
        self.rightSmoke = rightSmoke
    }
}
```

[image: emitters on plane]

the plane with the scene running (no emitters)

[image: plane in scene]

set the plane object to not paused (inside Plane.swift)

```
func setup() {

    self.isPaused = false

    if let leftSmoke = self.childNode(withName: "//leftSmoke") as? SKEmitterNode {
        self.leftSmoke = leftSmoke
        leftSmoke.isPaused = false
    }

    if let rightSmoke = self.childNode(withName: "//rightSmoke") as? SKEmitterNode {
        self.rightSmoke = rightSmoke
    }
}
```

and voila

[image]

> FYI

It probably works intermittently for you because you might have a break point set. Whenever you have a breakpoint set and the code stops it unPauses nodes automatically

Comment: Thanks. I played a lot with it since this question and figured out it was due to pausing. The hint was that if I used `advanceSimulationTime` the emitter would appear paused mid-simulation (vs not being visible at all in the beginning). I ended up creating an extension to SKNode that pauses/unpauses the node and all its descendants, and applied it to a scene